# I need to load all QFileSystemHierarchy from the start, to filter through all childs

Tags: qt

I am using QFileSystemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel. With some rootDir set to QFileSystemModel. And I'm using filterAcceptsRow to filter all child folders and files for contatining "filter" name. But function can't check all inner directories because of QFileSystemModel doesn't load all hierarchy before it needs it.

Look how different search results from QDir recursive search and using QFileSystemModel, just because QFileSystemModel don't know anything of some subfolders during the search. At the bottom results there is a case insensitivity, but it is not the huge difference.

[image]

How can I force QFileSystemModel load all hierarchy, no matter how much time it will take?

Comment: You are using PyQt, right? You've got some specific Qt version there, maybe? Could  you show you `QFileSystemModel` usage in the code?

I've tried in C++/Qt, like that: `const QString path {"C:\\Windows"};

    QFileSystemModel *fm = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fm->setRootPath(path);

    ui->dirView->setModel(fm);
    ui->dirView->setRootIndex(fm->index(path));` It showed all the subdirectories with the ability to exand any of them (and seeing the correct result).

Comment: Yes, I am using PyQt, some version of pyqt5. But you don't get the point) I am able to expand any folder, but I have a QSortFilterProxyModel over QFileSystemModel. And if you go through all indexes of QFileSYstemModel, you don't get all inner files and folder of the specified rootIndex. 
 At the screenshot you can see search results inside such model. And you can see that QFileSystemModel(bottom QTreeView) don't show results inside subfolders of "jdk1.7.0_55" for example. But if I open those subfolders manually without filter set, then the search will show results of that subfolders.

Comment: Same exact question here, sorry to see no one has an answer! One possible avenue is `QFileSystemModel.fetchMore(index)` which will tell the model to load the directory. The only issue I am running into is there is no signal once that directory is loaded...